# Flexbox Overflowing Body On Mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is my first post on Stack Overflow so thank you in advance for your thoughtfulness and assistance.

I am using flexbox on my site to change the order of my content on mobile. My site uses a sidebar and has some boxes at the bottom which are outside of the main content div.

```
<div id="content">

    <div class="10col">
        *content body*
    </div>

    <div class="2col">
        *sidebar*
    </div>

    <div id="greyboxes">
        *grey box content*
    </div>
```

When screen width allows this layout works great with the main content and sidebar side-by-side and the grey boxes below. The sidebar content are CTAs to other pages.

However on mobile I want the CTAs in the sidebar at the end of the page after the grey boxes.

Currently I'm using flexbox to reorder the content and it's working well. However on mobile it's shifting my content out of the body div.

**Mobile without Flexbox:**
-Body
-Sidebar
-Grey Boxes

**Reordered with Flexbox:**
-Body
-Grey Boxes
-Sidebar

I've searched Stack Overflow and Google but no one seems to be having a similar problem, and being new to flexbox I'm sure I'm doing something incorrectly.

If you use the inspector's mobile view to view http://dev.collegesurveyservices.com/our-evaluation-process/ you will see the problem.

Comment: The problem you're describing doesn't seem to exist in your website. Everything is aligning as you say you want. Also, please add all relevant code (enough to reproduce the problem) in your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hello Michael. Thank you very much for your response. I forgot to note that you have to view that page with the mobile inspector. Then all the content jumps to the right hand side. Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing: http://connard.co/cssscreenshot.jpg